# Emulation Station Keyboard Enter

Tags: keyboard, emulation, games

It's quite confusing when using EmulationStation with a keyboard that the `[A]` button is the only way to select a menu item. Usually the `<Enter>` (Return) key will not be assigned to `[A]` but, out of habit, users keep pressing `<Enter>` and expecting the menu item to be selected. In my case `<Enter>` was actually assigned to "Start" so it got really confusing.

Is there any way to have 2 keys (e.g. `<A>` and `<Enter>`) assigned to the `[A]` button function?

`[A]` = The virtual A button on console controllers

`<A>` = The physical A button on the keyboard

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it is not possible to assign 2 physical buttons to one virtual button so I ended up just assigning `<Enter>` to `[A]` and `<Esc>` to `[B]` and not using the keyboard for any console games.